# How to return the correct type of list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

If I have a method like this (for simplicity assume integers):

```
public static List<Integer> doSomething(List<Integer> list) {
   // logic here  
}
```

and I need for my processing to create internally a *new list* which I will create and somehow populate and return to the caller, how can I do it since I don't know what type of list the caller passed in?

I don't want to return a `List` of different type that what the caller passed in.

E.g. If the caller passed a `LinkedList` and I *don't* want to return an `ArrayList`.

How can this issue best be approached?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to return something of the same kind? Won't people be calling this with something like `ArrayList<Integer> a = doSomething(a);` in which case it will be cast automatically?

Comment: Why would they be calling it with `ArrayList a =`?The other friends who answered already complained/pointed out that there should not be an `ArrayList` floating around anywhere (i.e. use interfaces)

Comment: @KristianAntonsen That doesn't make sense; if I pass in a `LinkedList`, I can't randomly cast the return value to an arbitrary implementation and expect it to work.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can't you cast anything List to a LinkedList?

Comment: @KristianAntonsen What would it mean to cast an ArrayList to a LinkedList? Would you suddenly have the random access capability of an ArrayList? `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList`

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right. I guess I had an idea that it would do rather expensive restructuring of the data in memory.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen All casting does is attempt to reference one type as another--it doesn't *do* anything at runtime.

Comment: @DaveNewton Except with outboxing with outboxing I take it. ;-) Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen Boxing is not the same as casting; boxing is an operation on primitives.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to always return the same kind, if the user is allowed to pass in an Collections.UnmodifiableList wrapper.  Because it is tricky to determine if the list is one of these wrappers (you can't do instanceof Collections.UnmodifiableCollection) and, even if you could, you can't see the class of the underlying, wrapped List.

Comment: @DaveNewton `Integer i = (Integer) 1`, well that's a cast.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen And what happens under the covers? Primitives are a special case.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't tie your implementation to a particular implementation of `List`, the idea of using an interface is that, from the outside, it shouldn't matter what concrete class you're instantiating as long as it conforms to the `List` interface.

**EDIT :**

Anyway, here's a possible way:

```
List<Integer> lst1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Class<?> klass1 = lst1.getClass();
List<Integer> copy1 = (List<Integer>) klass1.newInstance();
System.out.println(copy1.getClass().getName());
> java.util.ArrayList

List<Integer> lst2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Class<?> klass2 = lst2.getClass();
List<Integer> copy2 = (List<Integer>) klass2.newInstance();
System.out.println(copy2.getClass().getName());
> java.util.LinkedList
```

As you can see in the console, the copies are instances of the same class as the original list.

Comment: I undertand what you are saying, but it is common for example to use `List` but assume that you have an `ArrayList` underneeth by default (I mean my concern is a ClassCastException somewhere)

Comment: Also swapping list implementation can affect performance elsewhere.

Comment: Some implementations *do* expect certain types of lists, though, notably random access lists.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get away with just using one of those two output types, then you can do

```
if (inputList instanceof RandomAccess) {
  // use an ArrayList
} else {
  // use a LinkedList.
}
```

The [`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface is meant to indicate that the implementation allows O(1) `get` operations.

> Marker interface used by `List` implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access. The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists.

By doing this, your APIs allow clients to defend their inputs.  They can pass in the result of `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` and be sure that it isn't modified by other code.

If you really know the input is a mutable list, you can `clone()` the list, then `clear()` it.  Both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` have public `clone()` methods which can be accessed reflectively.

Comment: I thought of that but `List` does not offer a `clone()`

Comment: @user384706, the `clone` method can be accessed reflectively if you know that your input is going to have a public clone method.

Comment: I like this solution.  However, it begs the question: if the user does pass in an unmodifiableList, does this method return an unmodifiableList too?  And, if this is desired behavior, how do you decide if the passed in list was unmodifiable?

Comment: @user949300, there is no easy way to detect whether a list is unmodifiable.  `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList` and Guava's `ImmutableList` are different approaches to the same end.  There are other effectively immutable list `Collections.emptyList` comes to mind, and some are partially mutable -- you can't add to the end of the output of `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to remove the list creation from the method. Have the caller decide how to create the list:

```
public static void doSomething(List<Integer> dest, List<Integer> src) {
```

Comment: I like this approach. Better than depending on newInstance in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Class.newInstance` to create a list of the passed in type:

```
public static List<Integer> doSomething(List<Integer> list)
{
    List<Integer> newList = null;
    try
    {
        newList = list.getClass().newInstance();
    }
    catch(InstantiationException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException e)
    {       
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    //Logic here

    return newList;
}

@Test
public void test()
{       
    List<Integer> testList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    List<Integer> resultList = doSomething(testList);
    Assert.assertEquals(testList.getClass(), resultList.getClass());
    Assert.assertNotSame(LinkedList.class, resultList.getClass());

    testList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    resultList = doSomething(testList);
    Assert.assertEquals(testList.getClass(), resultList.getClass());
    Assert.assertNotSame(ArrayList.class, resultList.getClass());       
}
```

Comment: I just posted (then deleted) something very similar.  As @Mike Samuel points out, this wont work so well if clients pass in a Unmodifiable wrapper.

Comment: @user949300: True, if there's a chance that an unmodifiable wrapper is used, I'd suggest going with Mike Samuels' solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really care what kind of object comes out, I would include that as a parameter to the method, like:

```
<T extends List<Integer>> T doSomething(Class<T> returnType,List<Integer> v)
    throws Exception
{
    // constructors for your return will be tricky :)
    // returnType.newInstance() will probably work.
    T result = returnType.newInstance();
    result.add(86); result.add(99);
    return result;
}
```